# Asterisk: Logging changed CALLERID(num) to CDR

Tags: asterisk

Asterisk logs call info into database via cdr.

If a call comes in via sip trunk the remote public telephone number often is supplied with the P-Asserted-Identity. This information normaly gets lost in CDR billing database.

```
[incoming]
exten => s,1,Set(CALLERID(num)=${SIP_HEADER(P-Asserted-Identity)})
 same => n,Dial(SIP/me)
```

This sets the P-Asserted-Identity as the Calling number for the next Dial but didn't get logged to CDR on hangup. Still the original CALLERID(num) is logged as src

Answer (score 0):

CDR uses current value of CALLERID(ani) instead of original CALLERID(num) for CDR(src) if CALLERID(ani) is not unset.

```
[incoming]
exten => s,1,Verbose(Incoming call on line 123)
; try to extract phone number from sip header P-Asserted-Identity
same => n,Set(FON=$["${SIP_HEADER(P-Asserted-Identity)}" : "<sip:([0-9+]+)"])
; This changes clid number wthout affecting cdr's (Just for Dial...)
same => n,ExecIf($[${ISNULL(${FON})}=0]?Set(CALLERID(num)=${FON})) 
; prevent beeing hacked by inject
same => n,Set(CALLERID(num)=${FILTER(+0123456789,${CALLERID(num)})})
; This tells cdr to use the new num for "automatic identified (billing) number" as src-field
same => n,Set(CALLERID(ani)=${CALLERID(num)})
same => n,Dial(SIP/me)
```

This is because you have to log the real originating extension instead of the general public service number (08000815) for internal billing.
In most cases the interesting part for billing is the real originating extension. Thats why CDR saves the original value of CALLERID(num).
CALLERID(num) often gets modified to general public number during an outgoing call. In this case you couldn't identify the real originating extension anymore by cdr.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to cdr any number of new fields, after that use like this

```
[incoming]
exten => s,1,Set(CALLERID(num)=${SIP_HEADER(P-Asserted-Identity)})
same =>n,Set(CDR(pai)=${SIP_HEADER(P-Asserted-Identity)})
same => n,Dial(SIP/me)
```

Note, you are responsible for add that field into table.